# Dynamically added input[type='number'] FormControl not setting value and validations for first time

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I'm using Angular 6.

I'm adding and displaying a dynamic FormControl 'precisionLimit' to my form on toggling a flag and removing it and its validations when flag becomes false.

Problem I'm facing here is:

My input type is 'number' and I'm adding new FormControl like:

```
this.surveyModalForm.addControl('precisionLimit', new FormControl(0, Validators.compose([NumberValidator.validate, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(5)])));
```

The issue over here is, when I'm toggling flag for the first time I'm getting and empty input box (which should have 0 value preset in it). Also one inputting the number, validations are also not working. I have also used `updateValueAndValidity()` method but it also failed to work.

Surprisingly when I toggle the flag for second time, value is set and validations are also working properly.

But it works in first attempt for the following code:

```
this.surveyModalForm.addControl('precisionLimit', new FormControl());
this.surveyModalForm.controls['precisionLimit'].setValue(0);
this.surveyModalForm.controls['precisionLimit'].setValidators([NumberValidator.validate, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(5)]);
```

So, I'm not getting what's going wrong with the first approach. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: My form is inside of a bootstrap modal.

Comment: your input type will be text and not number

Comment: My input type is 'number' only.